# Why doesn't my Cloud Function trigger receive the ID on create?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am following the code in this wiki page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events and have deployed the following code to a cloud function:

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore  } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

initializeApp()
const db = getFirestore();

exports.newDoc = functions.firestore
   .document('doc/{docId}')
   .onCreate((snap, context) => {
       console.log(context.params.docId);
       console.log(snap.data());
       db.collection('monitor').doc(uuid.v1()).set(snap.data()).then(_=>console.log('saved'));
});
```

When I add a doc to my 'doc' collection via the Firestore console it adds a document to my 'monitor' collection. When I check for the 'context.params.docId' log however there is a line there but it is completely empty (no contents at all). What am I missing?

Comment: I suggest being more specific about what you see in the log.  "empty lines" is not very descriptive.  You should also state more clearly what exactly you are doing to add the document. We should be able to follow your instructions and observe the same result that you're seeing.  Please edit the question to be more complete.

Comment: Fair suggestion. I've ammended my post to be more specific.

Comment: What does print the `console.log(snap.data());` line? Also, what happens if you change the last line by `return db.collection('monitor').doc(uuid.v1()).set(snap.data());`? See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for an explanation on why it is important to add `return` at the beginning of this line.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for the tip about the return. It doesn’t change my question but at least my function is completing properly now. I don’t understand your question about what prints the line

Comment: I would just like to know if this line (i.e. `console.log(snap.data());`) prints what is expected, i.e. the fields of the newly created document. When you say "my function is completing properly now" does it mean that the line `console.log(context.params.docId);` correctly prints the ID of the newly created document?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I get the contents of the data log and it matches the contents of the document in the ‘monitor’ collection. Unfortunately the Id still doesn’t log, I just meant that at least the function is exiting in an ‘expected manner’ for the cloud function runner.

Comment: You still haven't said what exactly you're doing to add the document.  Are you doing something in the web console?  Running a program?  What does that document look like?  We need instructions to follow that reproduce the behavior.  Also it might help if you screenshot the logs so we can see exactly what you see.

Comment: What happens if instead of doing `const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app'); const { getFirestore  } = require('firebase-admin/firestore'); ... const functions = require('firebase-functions');`(Node.js Admin SDK installation) you import the Cloud Functions and Admin SDK modules and initialize an admin app instance from which Cloud Firestore changes can be made, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I'm not sure if I fully understand your comment; based on my (limited) understanding, initializeApp should be functionally equivalent to admin.initializeApp and is simply using the new modular syntax

Comment: Ok, but if I’m not mistaking your code does not use the new syntax.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec which part is not using the new syntax? The lines you link to are just importing the modules and then calling admin.initializeApp which I believe is the non modular equivalent to initializeApp

Comment: `db.collection('monitor').doc(uuid.v1()).set(snap.data())`

Comment: To be clearer: I personally didn’t have the time to experiment the new modular syntax with Cloud Functions. However, seeing your code I would try with the “old” way of initialising. Maybe it will not change anything but it’s definitely what I would try at first.

Comment: Oh, OK. I did some more digging and was able to find my ID, but thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find my id by logging the entire context :) It is actually in the params object but as context.params.**pushId**